# Convert datetime YYYYMMDD to DDMMYYYY via T-SQL directly

Tags: t-sql, datetime

i can get my datetime populated as 2012-07-24 15:31:21

However, its not in the format that i want. This is my current query

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0), convert(varchar(20),GETDATE() , 120))
```

i need the above displayed datetime in the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

i have searched all over the place. Converting date format in T-SQL is available generally for datatype Varchar. Can someone advise me for datetime formatting via SQL directly?

thanks.

Comment: A `DATETIME` in SQL Server is an 8-byte binary number - it has **no formatting**. You only need to specify which formatting you want when you convert it to a `VARCHAR` for display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either that, or you can specify the date/time format directly as the parameter of the ToString method:

```
string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

or second answer is

You can use any culture that supports the dd-mm-yyyy format like the french one.

For example to format the date time now in a format dd-mm-yyyy you can do as follows:

```
cultureInfo culture = new cultureinfo("fr-FR");
string oFormatedDate = dtNow.ToString("d", culture);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be DateTime.Now.ToString("dd//MM//yyyy hh:mm:ss"); See OP requirement

Comment: `i need the above displayed datetime in the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.` OP says. Does `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");` do the same?

Comment: @nawfal yes thats what i wanted but i guess i'll convert it via code-behind using varchar format. thanks alot bro:)